# Writing a text on the user interface using wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Taking the following code: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/wx_mpl_dynamic_graph.py.txt which is actually the second code example that we can find on 
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis

I want to add some text on the user interface to show the current iteration at each step. Something like the following example. How can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want to do is add that to the on_redraw_timer method. It appears to fire every time the plot is updated, so I would think that that would be where you'd want to write to your text control as well.

Just make sure you stop writing if it is paused.